# UML Object Diagram: Parent or Child

Tags: java, inheritance, uml, object-diagram

Let's say I have the following class :

```
public class ParentClass{}
```

And one of its children classes is :

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{}
```

Let's consider another class :

```
public class Foo{
    
    private ParentClass field;
    
    public Foo(){
        
        field = new ChildClass();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        
    }
    
}
```

When drawing the Object Diagram of `foo` I don't know if I have to write `ChildClass` :

[image]

Or `ParentClass` :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program *field* is an instance of *ChildClass*, the goal of the object diagram is to show instances with their effective type (and their attributes value if they have) => the right diagram to use is

[image]

---

[edit from remarks to my answer]

It is also legal to use the second diagram, but that one hide the fact the instance is *for sure* an instance of *ChildClass*, so better to use the first diagram to indicate that.

I forgot to mention in both your diagrams the *line* between the two instances does not correspond to the alone association between them, a right way to do for the first diagram is :

[image]

considering your instance of *Foo* is saved through a variable named *foo* it seems reasonable to name *foo* your instance of *Foo*

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to do it this way but I wasn't sure.

Comment: When placing the name of the object in front of the colon it would be even clearer.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not a big user of object diagrams, but I would have used `foo:Foo --- field:ParentClass` because in the known class of `field` is `ParentClass`.    Where is it said in the specs that it shall show the effective type?  I only found page 125 "*The purpose of an InstanceSpecification is to show what is of interest about the instance. The instance conforms to each classifier of the InstanceSpecification*...", which would leave the choice of the one, or the other, or both alltogether depending on what is of interest for the diagram.

Comment: Moreover isn't the spec sentence "*It is important to keep in mind that InstanceSpecification is a model element and should not be confused with the instance that it is modeling.*" an open door for not necessarily using the effective type of an object ?

Comment: @Christophe may be I was not clear enough in my answer, I did not say the second diagram is wrong. Knowing the instance of *Foo* is associated for sure with an instance of *CHildClass* why to hide that in the diagram ? Why do we make diagrams, to hide knowledge/information or to show it ? For me *show what is of interest about the instance* starts by the effective type of the instance in that context.

Comment: @Christophe `I would have used foo:Foo --- field:ParentClass` you are wrong, *field* is not the name of the instance of *ParentClass/ChildClass* but the name of the attribute/association end. I edit my answer to improve diagram representation

Comment: Learned something new too :-)

Comment: @bruno Correct me if I'm wrong, here field is the name of the ChildClass field in Foo, if this ChildClass object was passed for example by the constructor and had a reference we would write its name in front of :ChildClass? Basically you put the field name next to the arrow link, and the name in front of the colon if it has a reference in the outer scope?

Comment: @dylanbatio first you can name the instances as you like, whatever the way there are managed in the source code if this one exist. The instance's name is written before ':' into the rectangle representing the instance. Considering the representation of the association it is like in a class diagram, see § 9.8.5 from page 129 of [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1)